# Geometry of affine euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the line $\ell$ passes through the points $A(3,1,2,4)$ and $B(4,2,3,6)$, and 2D plane $\Pi$ through the points $C(2,1,3,-1), D(6,1,0,2),E(3,0,2,0)$. Find an equation of the common perpendicular to $\ell$ and $\Pi$ and its length.

**My approach:** Easy to note that $\ell$ can be written as $(3,1,2,4)+\langle (1,1,1,2)\rangle$ and $\Pi$ as $(2,1,3,-1)+\langle (4,0,-3,3),(1,-1,-1,1)\rangle$.

And I will use the following theorem from my lecture notes:

> The distance between two affine subspaces $(\mathfrak{C},U)$ and
>   $(\mathfrak{B},W)$ is equal to the length of orthogonal component of
>   the vector $\overline{PQ}$ connecting any point $P\in \mathfrak{C}$
>   with any point $Q\in \mathfrak{B}$, relative to the subspace $U+W$:
>   $$\text{dist}(\mathfrak{C},\mathfrak{B})=|\text{ort}_{U+W}
>  \overline{PQ}| \quad \text{for all} \quad P\in \mathfrak{C},Q\in
>  \mathfrak{B}$$

In my case $U=\langle (1,1,1,2)\rangle, W=\langle (4,0,-3,3),(1,-1,-1,1)\rangle$ and let's take $A=(3,1,2,4), C=(2,1,3,-1)$. Then $\overline{CA}=(1,0,-1,5)$. And it's easy to show that $U+W=\langle (1,1,1,2),(4,0,-3,3),(1,-1,-1,1)\rangle=\langle a_1,a_2,a_3\rangle$.

From linear algebra we know that projection of $\overline{CA}$ into $U+W$ which is the vector $\text{pr}_{U+W}\overline{CA}=\alpha a_1+\beta a_2+\gamma a_3$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ can be computed from the following matrix  equation: $$G(a_1,a_2,a_3)\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta \\
\gamma
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
(a_1,\overline{CA}) \\
(a_2,\overline{CA}) \\
(a_3,\overline{CA})
\end{bmatrix},$$ where $G(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is the Gram matrix of vectors $a_1,a_2,a_3$. And from computations I got the matrix equation $$\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 7 & 1 \\
7 & 34 & 10 \\
1 & 10 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta \\
\gamma
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
10 \\
22 \\
7
\end{bmatrix}$$

with solution $\alpha=\frac{4}{3},\beta=\frac{-1}{6},\gamma=\frac{11}{6}$. Then computation shows us that $\text{pr}_{U+W}\overline{CA}=(\frac{5}{2},\frac{-1}{2},0,4)$. Then orthogonal component is equal to: $$\text{ort}_{U+W}\overline{CA}=\overline{CA}-\text{pr}_{U+W}\overline{CA}=(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2},-1,1).$$

Then by theorem distance between $\ell$ and $\Pi$ is $$|\text{ort}_{U+W}\overline{CA}|=\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+2}=\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

And this answer coincides with answer in the book.

**Trouble starts here** when I am trying fo find an equation of common perpendicular. Orthogonal component intersect plane $\Pi$ at the point $R=(2,1,3,-1)+\text{pr}_{U+W}\overline{QP}=(2,1,3,-1)+(\frac{5}{2},\frac{-1}{2},0,4)=(\frac{9}{2},\frac{1}{2},3,3)$. So the common perpendicular passes through the point $R$ and $A$ so it can be written as $$A+\langle \overline{RA}\rangle =(3,1,2,4)+\langle (\frac{3}{2},\frac{-1}{2},1,1)\rangle.$$
And the book's answer is different than mine I have checked my computations at least 3 time and everything is correct.

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with the second part of my solution, please?

**EDIT** (uniqueness of common perpendicular): We will show that the common perpendicular is unique if and only if $U\cap W=\{0\}$.

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose by contradiction there is an $x\in U\cap W$ such that $x\neq 0$. Since $\text{pr}_{U+W}\overline{PQ}\in U+W$ then we can write it in two ways: $$\text{pr}_{U+W}\overline{PQ}=u+w=(u+x)+(w-x)$$
Let's take $P'=P+u, Q'=P'+\text{ort}_{U+W}\overline{PQ}$ (as in the proof of the theorem) and $P''=P+u+x, Q''=P''+\text{ort}_{U+W}\overline{PQ}$.

Let $\ell'$ and $\ell ''$ be lines passing trough points $P', Q'$ and $P'', Q''$, respectively.

Then $\ell'$ can be written as $P'+\langle \overline{P'Q'}\rangle =P'+\langle \text{ort}_{U+W}\overline{PQ}\rangle $ and $\ell''$ can be written as $P''+\langle \overline{P''Q''}\rangle =P''+\langle \text{ort}_{U+W}\overline{PQ}\rangle $.

Since the line is unique then $P''=P'+\alpha v$ where $v=\text{ort}_{U+W}\overline{PQ}$. And we can rewrite it in this way: $P+u+x=P+u+\alpha v$ or equivalently $P+x=P+\alpha v$ and it follows that $x=\alpha v$. Since $x\neq 0$ then $\alpha \neq 0$ and we have that $\alpha^{-1}x=v$ and since by definition $v=\text{ort}_{U+W}\overline{PQ}\in (U+W)^{\perp}$ it means that $v$ is orthogonal to $x$, i.e. $(v,x)=0$ which gives us that $(\alpha^{-1} x,x)=\alpha^{-1}(x,x)=0$ and hence $(x,x)=0$ and it means that $x=0$ which is a contradiction because $x\neq 0$.

$\Leftarrow$ How to prove this part?

Comment: The perpendicular passes through the line but not at the point $A$.

Comment: @copper.hat, probably i am misunderstanfing the definition of common perpendicular. Could you explain it please? Also why it should pass through $A$?

Comment: It does **not** pass through $A$. It passes through some other point on the line.

Comment: I only have my phone now, so a proper reply is difficult. you are essentially minimizing the distance between the line and the plane. The minimizing point won't necessarily pass through $A$ or $B$

Comment: @copper.hat, unfortunately i am still confused. I still cannot get what is wrong with my reasoning. Could you clarify thoughts when you will be free, please. I spent smth like 2 days to this problem

Comment: Why common perpendicular should pass through the point $A$? And what is wrong with my reasoning

Comment: Still only have phone. Your line passes through $A$ but not through the plane. You need to find a point on the line (or plane) so that the perpendicular passes through the plane (or line).

Comment: My line passes through $A$ and $R$ and $R$ is the point of the plane. Look how i computed $R$, it lies on the plane

Comment: I reworded my answer and added a note. The issue is that the projection combines the displacements on the line **and** the plane, so you cannot just add the projection to $A$ or $C$.

Comment: I added another clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the line be $A-t_1 d_1$ and the plane $C+t_2d_2 + t_3 d_3$. (I chose the $-$ sign on the line for my own convenience later, but it doesn't matter as long as you make the appropriate modifications.) The $d_1,d_2,d_3$ are from the corresponding vectors in the question paragraph starting with
"My approach". I chose $d_4=(-3,1,-2,2)^T$ because I prefer whole numbers :-).

You wish to find the equation of the line in the direction $d_4$ (the common perpendicular) that passes through the line and the plane.

You know the direction, you need to find a point on either the line or plane to finish.

In other words, you wish to solve
$A-t_1 d_1 = C+t_2d_2 + t_3 d_3 + t_4 d_4$, or
$D t = A-C$, where $D$ has $d_k$ as columns.

Solving this gives $t={1 \over 6} (8,-1,11,3)^T$.

Hence the point on the line is $A'=A-t_1 d_1 = {1 \over 3}(5,-1,2,4)^T$
and so the equation of the perpendicular passing through **both** line and plane is $A'+td_4$.

The distance between the two must be given by $\|t_4d_4\| = { 1\over 2} \sqrt{18}= {3 \over \sqrt{2}}$.

**Note**:

The issue in the question is that the projection onto $U+W$ corresponds to 
$t_1d_1+t_2d_2+t_3 d_3 = A-C-t_4d_4$.

In order to find the point(s) that the perpendicular passes through you need
to compute $A'=A-t_1d_1$ **or** $C'=C+t_2d_2 + t_3 d_3$.

You cannot just add the projection onto $A$ or $C$ as it combines the shifts.

**Clarification**:

The problem is equivalent to solving $\min_{u \in U, w \in W} \|A+u - (C+w)\|$.
If you solve this problem, then $A'=A+u, C'=C+w$ will be the points on the line and plane corresponding to the closest distance and the perpendicular line will be
$A'+t(C'-A')$ (or however you want to write it).

The issue with the projection, is that you are solving a slightly different problem,
$\min_{n \in U+W} \|A-C -n\|$ and there is no way apriori to separate $n$ into the $u,w$ parts in order to get $A',C'$. In particular, you cannot just add $n$ to $A$.

However, since the vectors that make up the subspaces $U,W$ are linearly independent, you can uniquely find the $u,w$ such that $n=w-u$.

In particular, with $n={1 \over 2} (5,-1,0,8)^T$ we have
$u=-{1 \over 3} (4,4,4,8)^T$ and $w={1 \over 6} (7, -11, -8, 8)^T$
and so $A' = A + u = {1 \over 3}(5,-1,2,4)^T$.

Hence one way of writing the perpendicular line is
${1 \over 3}(5,-1,2,4)^T + \lambda (-3,1,-2,2)^T$.

**Addendum**:

Suppose there are distinct $u,u' \in \mathfrak{C}$ and $w,w' \in \mathfrak{B}$ such that $p=u-w=u'-w'$ where
$p$ is the common perpendicular. Then $u-u' = w-w'$ and so $U \cap W \neq \{0\}$.

However, I think it is easier to note that
$\min_{u \in U, w \in W} \|u-w\| = \min_{x \in V-W} \|x\|$.
 (I'm assuming finite dimensions so the subspaces are closed.)

Since $V-W$ is a (closed) convex set there is a unique minimiser $\hat{x}$ and
there must exist some $u \in U, w \in W$ such that $\hat{x} = u-w$.

Then we see that the $u,w$ are unique **iff** $V \cap W = \{0\}$.

Comment: Look. I figured out the vector which is orthogonal to the plane and the line, right? So I can take any point on the line $\ell$, for example $A$ and the line through this point with directional vector $(-3,1,-2,2)$ will intersect the plane $\Pi$. What is wrong here? Can we discuss it in chat?

Comment: I don't have the time for chat now. You have the correct direction. But you cannot take just any point on the line. Keep in mind this is $\mathbb{R}^4$, the line through $A$ in the given direction vector **does not** intersect the plane.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your  help! I give up. This problem is probably beyond of my knowledge

Comment: Don't give up. Do you see the distinction between the two minimisation problems in the Clarification section above? They are related. And if $U \cap W = \{0\}$ then they are equivalent.

Comment: Not to be honest. Probably i am bit tired of doing this problem. I spent smth like two days believing that my solutions and i cannot understand right now nothing :)

Comment: Well, that is the key to understanding why your solution does not work. You have the correct direction, but you must choose the point on the line (or the plane) so that a line through that point (with the special direction) intersects the plane. The line from $A$ does not intersect the plane.

Comment: BTW, am I right that common perpendicular is unique if and only in $U\cap W=\{0\}$?

Comment: Yes. In this case it would mean the line is parallel to the plane.

Comment: Take a look at my edit(uniqueness of common perpendicular) please? Could you show me the proof of the converse? One part i solved quite easily but cannot do the converse :(

Comment: I am trying to prove the uniqueness of common perpendicular in general case (i mean the theorem which I attached in my question).

Comment: See edits. ${}{}$

Comment: In your addendum when you say that $p$ is common perpendicular you meant that it is vector orthogonal to both planes, right?

Comment: That is correct. It might help to think of two lines in 3 dimensions to get some intuition.

Comment: Yeah your right. If two lines in the 3d space are parallel, i.e. $U\cap W\neq 0$ then such line is not unique. If they are skew then such line is unique.

Comment: Sorry but let me ask you one more question: 1) why in your addendum this common perpendicular $p$ is the same for both distinct lines? It confuses me a bit. 2) you wrote $u-u'=w-w'$ but in affine space (in my definition) you cannot add two points. Instead of this you can operate with point and the vector. Could you clarify those moments, please?

Comment: 2) An affine space has a group action of vectors on an affine space, say $f:V \times A \to A$, and in addition, the map $v \mapsto f(v,a)$ is a bijection and so defines a 'subtraction' $-:A \times A \to V$ which has the expected properties.

Comment: 1) From your theorem the orthogonal component (a vector) joining any two points in $\mathfrak{C}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ is the same.